# Publishing to Azure taking too much time

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013

We are deploying our application to Azure through the publish option integrated in visual studio 2013. But it's taking too much time publish the site to Azure every time. 
By looking at the Azure App Service Activity tab, it seems that publish tool pushing all the files to Azure,  even files that not changed at all. I am want to publish only the modified files to Azure . Does the is there any options for that ?

Comment: Did you have `Delete all existing files prior to publish` checked in your publish settings?

Comment: @ramiramilu Where can I see that option ?

Comment: @ramiramilu I think you have got that setting slightly wrong - it is `Remove additional files at destination` - which obviously isn't going to have an impact on the issue here

Comment: @MichaelB No, we do have an option to Delete all existing files.

Comment: As @MichaelB said I too see the option he mentioned but not the other one for Delete all existing files prior to publish

Comment: @Midhun I believe that is a vs2012 option, they changed it to additional files in vs2013

Comment: @MichaelB  Ok. But every time publishing all the files does n't make sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, on that part I've really no idea, I'm not a good enough programmer to write anything big enough for that to be a concern :P

Comment: Is this a .NET application - are you using Nuget packages ? If so you don't need to upload the NuGet packages, they will be restored...

Comment: Another option is to setup continues deployment on your site. e.g https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/

Comment: @AIDANCASEY it;s a Asp.net MVC Web application. I am not uploading anything specific I am just publishing the site .

Comment: @XiaominWu Thanks for that Info , I will check it.